Cartoon Network (Pakistan or India) show around 2007 or 2009 featuring a brother and sister who fight but later become allies
I remembered a cartoon I watched when I was a kid (around 9 or 10 years old). Now, I can't remember the name, only snippets of it.
I remember the show was set in a modern urban environment but had fantasy elements, probably made in a Western country. I think it was related to mythical creatures or animals, but I'm not sure. The main character, who was male, had a sister who was probably his enemy at first until they realized the truth and became allies.
I think both he and his sister could transform to fight. The main character also had a female friend, I believe. I remember that his sister's master knew about their relationship. They probably didn’t have parents, and I recall a scene where they fought again, though I can’t remember why. It had something to do with her master corrupting her or taking control of her.
I’m not sure, but the main character was at least a young adult in his early 20s or a late teenager, around 16 or 17. I also remember that his sister’s power had a dark source like it was evil, while the main character’s power came from a light source.

Might it be Legend of the Dragon?

The show begins with the passing of the previous Golden Dragon to the afterlife. Ang and Ling Leung, seventeen-year-old fraternal twins born in the year of the Dragon, are next in line for the Golden Dragon power band to defend the mortal world from evil. Ang does not believe he will become the Golden Dragon, as Ling is the best fighter at the Dragon Dojo. Ling is positive that she will become the Golden Dragon. However, when Master Chin Ho calls upon the power of the Golden Dragon to choose who will be the next Golden Dragon, it chooses Ang. Humiliated and furious, Ling storms out of the temple and is tempted by the dark and evil power of the Shadow Dragon. From then on, Ang is forced to fight his twin sister.

I ran into it on the TV Tropes page for Sibling Yin-Yang. It's also has its own works page.
Opening



